# I don't know where those third-party Python packages have been installed on MacOS?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm currently doing Natural Language Processing with Python. I installed NLTK package by using `pip install nltk`. I have several Pythons on my Mac, but I use 3.4 mostly.

Now, I've downloaded a segmenter from Stanford that could do Chinese language segmentation([Stanford Word Segmenter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml)), but it might need me to do some changes on the original NLTK package, namely, I have to write an API file called `stanford_segmenter.py` and then put it into the `nltk/tokenize/` directory.

The problem is I don't really know where the NLTK package having been installed, I actually don't know where the `lib` directory of Python 3.4 is on MacOS. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic approach to locating a package in the file system is importing it and looking at the `__file__` attribute.

On the commandline, you can e.g. run

```
python -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__file__)"
```

It will show you where the top level`nltk` (probably `__init__.py`) file is located.